# java.sql.SQLException: Field 'otherMenuItems_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm trying to create a field in an entity with a many to many relationship I keep getting `fieldname_id` doesn't have a default value error.

In the same Model, I have a different field of the same type. That one doesn't generate any errors.

For the new field, I only changed the variable name, but it generates an error.

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem extends Model {
  @Required
  public String title;

  @Column(length = 3)
  public String currency;

  public double price;

  public double quantity = 1;

  public String size;

  @ManyToOne
  public Category category;

  public String crustType;

  public Long menuItemId;//reference to main or parent menu item from which this order item is based on

  @ManyToMany
  public List<MenuItem> menuItems; No error


  @ManyToMany
public List<MenuItem> othermenuItems; Causes error



@ManyToOne
  public Recipe recipe;

  @ManyToOne
  public Activity status;

  @OneToOne
  public FoodOrder order;
}



@Entity
public class MenuItem extends Model{
  public String description;

  @Required
  public String title;

  public String shortCode;

  @Column(length = 3)
  public String currency;

  public Double price;

  public String weight;



  @ManyToMany
  public List<MenuItem> menuItems;

  public String size;

  @ManyToOne
  public Category category;

  public Boolean isAvailable = true;

  @ManyToOne
  public Recipe recipe;

//  @ManyToOne
//  public RecipeV2 recipeV2;

  public String imageUrl;
  public Blob image;

  @Index(name="menuItemIndex")
  @Column(name="itemIndex", length=255)
  public String itemIndex;

  public Date logDate;
  public Date lastModified;

  public String recipeId;

}

@OnApplicationStart
public class LoadTestData extends Job {

    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        if (play.Play.mode.isDev() && !Play.id.equalsIgnoreCase("production")) {
            Logger.info("Deleting all data");
            Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
            Logger.info("Loading order item...");
            Fixtures.loadModels("test-data/orderItem.yml");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I load data from a yaml file...

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'othermenuItems_id' doesn't have a default value
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
>
> at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)

Comment: Why do you try to get the same ManyToMany mapping twice?

Comment: We cant find the bug in your code if you don't post the code. Post the **actual** code of the entities, and post the code which causes this exception to be thrown. It complains about the ID of your menu item, but you've chosen to hide this ID from the code you posted.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer why not. Don't you have personal contacts and professional contacts? Or done tasks and todo tasks?

Comment: @JBNizet But wouldn't it be better to hold them in separate tables or tag them and only get one list and separate it later in a service? Appreciate your answer cause I'm relative new to all this :)

Comment: "Why do you try to get the same ManyToMany mapping twice?" - I did that because even though the field types are the same, I need to separate the data. I guess I could have created a new model to handle the second field, but I didn't because the same field would be in both.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer It's a ManyToMany association. The task "get married" could be done for you, but todo for someone else. So you can't tag the entity Task with "done" or "todo". That's just an example. The point is to explain that it's perfectly reasonable to have two different associations between two entities.

Comment: @JBNizet I've edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok thank you. I got it know. :)

Comment: And your edit doesn't add any code to the question, although I think I clearly advised yoy to post the relevant code. When asking about a bug in code, the code matters.

Comment: So the problem is not with your code, but ith the Fixtures code of the Play framework, or with your yaml data. I don't know Play, so I can't answer.